# Magento 2: Should the static version index?

Tags: magento2, seo, static-content-deploy

I'm new to Magento. I'm wondering about static versions.

I understand their purpose, but wondering if for SEO they should be indexable or non-index?

Thanks.

Comment: The panda 4 update back in 2014  requires that google be able to access your css and js files. If you don't block your static  content from your robots.txt you should be fine. You can read a bit more at the link https://yoast.com/google-panda-robots-css-js/